# Inserir n pontos de um vetor randomicamente em uma matriz qualquer em java

Tags: java, array, matriz, random, inserir

Sou iniciante no java, eu queria saber se existe alguma função que facilitasse a minha vida para que:

tendo um vetor de **n** posições preenchido com números (pre-definidos), distribuir esses números nas posições de uma matriz de forma aleatória.

Por exemplo: tendo um vetor de 10 posições com 10 números e uma matriz 15x10, distribuir esses 10 números de forma aleatória nas posições da matriz, no caso, a posição que eventualmente não for preenchida não teria problemas.

Grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há necessidade de nenhuma biblioteca para essa tarefa tão simples, talvez apenas a [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) para te dar as posições aleatórias.

Exemplo:

```
Random random = new Random();
matriz[random.nextInt(15)][random.nextInt(10)] = vetor[i];
```